# Find the smallest triangular number with more than 500 factors

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, factors

I wrote a program about triangular numbers, which are derived from the sum of natural numbers one after the other. For example, the third triangular number is equal to: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6.

I want to find divisors of triangular numbers. for example the third triangular number have 4 divisors which equal to : 1,2,3,6.

Some triangular number with their divisors:

- **1**: 1
- **3**: 1,3
- **6**: 1,2,3,6
- **10**: 1,2,5,10
- **15**: 1,3,5,15
- **21**: 1,3,7,21
- **28**: 1,2,4,7,14,28

I want to find the smallest triangular number which has more than 500 divisors.  This program works, but is too slow to find the 500th.  How can I optimize my program?

```
    def triangular(n):
        a= []
        for i in range (2,n):
            if n % i == 0 :
            a.append(i)
        if len(a) > 498:
            return True
        else :
            a.clear()
            return False
    x=1
    n=x
    while x>0:
        if triangular(n):
            print(n)
            break
        else:
            n+=x+1
            x+=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
        if len(a) > 498:
            return True
        else :
            a.clear()
            return False
```

you could just

```
        return len(a) > 498
```

as there's no point in clearing `a`.

The n-th triangle number is \$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\$, so you could factor both n and n+1 and combine their factorizations.

Takes less than a second:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import prod
from functools import cache

@cache
def factorize(n):
    factorization = Counter()
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        while n % d == 0:
            factorization[d] += 1
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
        factorization[n] += 1
    return factorization

n = triangle = 0
while True:
    n += 1
    triangle += n
    factorization = factorize(n) + factorize(n + 1) - factorize(2)
    divisors = prod(power + 1 for power in factorization.values())
    if divisors > 500:
        print(triangle, divisors)
        break
```

Comment: He starts at 2 and ends at n, so he’s accounting for 1 and n. That’s why he stopped at 498.

Comment: @my_first_c_program Ah, of course, thanks. I removed that remark.

Comment: Do not factorize both `n` and `n+1`. Reuse one from the previous iteration.

Comment: @vnp That's what `@cache` does.

Answer (score 2):

The function `triangular()` is poorly named.  I would recommend writing a function that simply counts factors - and remember that each factor `f` of `n` has a corresponding partner `n/f`, so you only have to count half the factors, and can stop testing above `sqrt(n)`.  You might even omit the special case for square `n`, since triangular numbers can't also be square.

We could write a *generator* for the triangular numbers, rather than mixing that in to the logic of the main function:

```
import itertools

def triangular_numbers():
    return itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1))
```

Then we can just find the first item from that generator which satisfies the condition:

```
import functools
import itertools

def triangular_numbers():
    return itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1))

def factors(n):    
    return len(set(functools.reduce(list.__add__, 
                                    ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(next(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: factors(x) <= 500, triangular_numbers())))
```

There are more efficient ways of counting factors.  A better approach might be to calculate the **prime factorization** and use that to work out the total number of factors.

Comment: Could also `sum` the lists and use a positive `filter`.